# PHP - Sort by value Ascending then by value Random

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to get a winner element from a pool of elements inside an array. The element with the less ocurrences is the winner:

```
$answer_list = [7,7,7,5,4,1,2,2,3,1,3,7,7,4,1,4,5,5,4,5];
$answer_list_counts = array_count_values($answer_list);
asort($answer_list_counts);

array(6) {
  [2]=> 2
  [3]=> 2
  [1]=> 3
  [4]=> 4
  [5]=> 4
  [7]=> 5
}
```

After the sort, the winning element would be $answer_list_counts[0] most of the times.

But if there are multiple elements sharing the same number of ocurrences, the one with the lowest key will always win. Ideally this should be randomized.

So in this case the winner shoule be the answer with key `2` or `3`, but at the moment key `2` always wins. A second "random" sort which respects the initial sorting would fix this, but I can't get it to work.

I tried using shuffle after the asort:

```
$winner = shuffle($answer_list_counts)[0];
```

But this solution doesn't respect the first sort, it just shuffles the entire array randomly.

Comment: Can you post the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Added the entire code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-keys.php) you can search keys for a specific value. So you can first reduce the results and then do the shuffle:

```
$elementsWithLessOccurences = array_keys($answer_list_counts, $answer_list_counts[0]);
$winner = shuffle($elementsWithLessOccurences)[0];
```

Nice side effect is that you get the actual element and not it's occurence count...